# Docker swarm number of services from single docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am facing an issue, my docker compose file has 230 services to be created.
When I deploy the docker compose yml file to docker swarm cluster I see that the first 114 services start proeprly.
For remaining services, they are in running state but their replication remains 0/1 means no docker instance is created.
I monitored them for 1 day but the status was same. Also there were no logs present for these services.
Please let me know whether there is a limitation on number of services from single docker-compose file. Or I need to fix some things on my server or docker swarm cluster.

Comment: I am not aware of any automatic limit.  If you use resource limit/reseveration and your node(s) dont have enough resources, swarm will not schedule the task.

Comment: There is no limitation on number of services you can create from docker-compose file, the only limitation is the resources available in your swarm cluster. Every container consumes some resources(cpu,ram,vols etc), if this cannot be provided by swarm it stops creating services. Quick test to check is to try create one more container when docker-compose stops creating services instances, there you can see the error